# Laravel custom collection property doesnt exist

Tags: php, laravel, oop

so I have this custom collection in my controller and I would like to use magic getters but I am getting this error:

**Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance.**

```
$test = collect( ["title" => "title", "heading" => "heading"]);
echo $test->title; // This doesnt work
echo $test->get('title'); // this works
```

Is it possible to use magic getters or I can only access it by get method?

Answer (score 0):

laravel collection class has the magic getter implementation in the following way

```
public function __get($key)
    {
        if (! in_array($key, static::$proxies)) {
            throw new Exception("Property [{$key}] does not exist on this collection instance.");
        }

        return new HigherOrderCollectionProxy($this, $key);
    }
```

since your query does not belongs to the static::$proxies (which are used for further modification or actions to be done in the array like sort, group) array it throws the error. so get the value with $test->get('title', 'default value')

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you should be able to use array-like access:

```
echo $test['title'];
```

If you have multiple records in your collection you can change how you access the records with the `->keyBy()` method. Example:

```
$collection = collect([
        ['id' => 13, 'name' => 'Fred'],
        ['id' => 42, 'name' => 'Mike']
    ]);
```

Initially, it acts like a numerically-indexed array. Here, we can call `$collection[0]` to interact with:

```
['id' => 13, 'name' => 'Fred']
```

But calling:

```
$collection = $collection->keyBy('id');
```

makes `$collection[13]` now return this value.

A similar operation can be performed with `->keyBy('name')` to be able to access `$collection['Fred']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the collection instance and then programmatically populate it using `object` method

With that you can now access the collection prioperties as you normally do

```
$collection = collect();
$collect->title = 'title';
$collection->heading = 'heading';
echo $collection->title // this now works
```